# Android Animation , a simple linear_interpolator

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation

I want to animate a list it will be hidden under the screen, bottomMargin is a negative value
then when I click a button, I animate it up, then after the animation is done "onAnimationEnd" I modify the margin to make it stop in the place of the animation ends.

it's working good when animate down, I don't see any thing after it goes to -ve

BUT in the animate up, it's go more than it have too, and modifying the margin, make a bad effect "as it's not stopping where it have to"
here is what I'm doing

animation down:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <!-- same animation, linear interpolator -->
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:toYDelta="25%p"
        android:duration="500"
     />
</set>
```

animation up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <!-- same animation, linear interpolator -->
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:toYDelta="-25%p"
        android:duration="500"
     />
</set>
```

the code run in the onAnimationEnd:

```
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) playerLayout.getLayoutParams();
if (params.bottomMargin == 0) {
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, playerLayout.getHeight()* -1);
} else {
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
playerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

what is wrong!!!
in the animate up, the animated area start to appear normally, then suddenly it goes up fast upper than the normal place, then the modification of margin make it suddenly re-position to the normal place.

here a link to a video showing the problem https://dl.dropbox.com/u/51616029/irrelevant/20121005323.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Try just placing the `View` you want to animate in its final location in your layout to begin with and set its initial visibility to invisible (either in xml with `android:visibility="invisible"` or in code with `setVisibility(INVISIBLE)`).  When you are ready to animate your view, just make the view visible as you start the animation.

```
onStartAnimation(Animation animation) {
    myView.setVisible(VISIBLE);
}
```

and your animation could just be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="500"   
 />
```

This way you don't have to worry about making complex layout changes at all.

Comment: I did, as you see, after the animation down done, I add the following margin "params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, playerLayout.getHeight()* -1);"

and after up, I add this "params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);"

Comment: My suggestion was saying to just make the view invisible after the down animation finishes and visible just before the up animation starts. Do not worry about calling `setMargin()` at all, as it would be unnecessary.

Comment: but I want a part from that layout to be visible

Comment: Ah, in your original post you said you wanted a list "hidden under the screen."  If the list is not supposed to be 100% hidden then this wouldn't work.  If it is supposed to be 100% hidden, then it should work; I was not suggesting making the entire layout invisible, only the list itself.

Comment: please find a link at the end of the question, for a video showing the problem